# Datatables: Is there a way to disable pagination-controls when data fits on first page?

Tags: jquery, datatables

As the subject says: I have a "potentially large" table, but it sometimes only shows a few records and would not need pagination. In that case the disabled pagination controls are "aesthetically disturbing" and I wanted to only show them when required.
So I came up with this:

```
$('#foo').DataTable{
bla,
"bPaginate":(10<$("#foo tbody tr").length),
bla
}
```

Works fine - but I was wondering if there is perhaps an option in DataTables to do that automagically?

Comment: Strange code you are using because `$("#foo").length` can only be evaluated as 1 in your code.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange indeed - because it works. I'm using jQuery and was assuming this would select the element based on its ID and `length`is supposed to return the number of rows in that table....

Comment: Ya it will but as IDs must be unique in document context, .length property can only returns one even they are multiple elements with same ID. If no element with this ID is in DOM, this part of code won't be reached.

Comment: Yes, but as I only have one table with that ID, this is not really a problem...

Comment: following your updated comment: `length is supposed to return the number of rows in that table` So you mean: `$("#foo tr").length` instead

Comment: Ahhh....now I see - yes, certainly you are right, I missed that bit. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Wolff, it should be `$("#foo tbody tr").length`, otherwise you will `<tr>` in `<thead>` as well.